# I followed all the things mentioned in the documentation of flutter stripe package but it is not working for me

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':stripe_android:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':stripe_android:compileDebugKotlin'
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':stripe_android:debugCompileClasspath'.
> > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.8.10\6d5560a229477df9406943d5feda5618e98eb64c\kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10.jar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.8.10\6d5560a229477df9406943d5feda5618e98eb64c\kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: EOFException, message: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

I tried all the thing mentioned in documenation of flutter
It is 9.3.0 version of flutter stripe